# Point Two Websites to Two Different PCs on Same Network?

Tags: mysql, apache, localhost, portforwarding

I have a network at home. On this network, I have two computers. Each of these computers have apache and mysql installed on them. I have two websites that I would like to point to my network, one to each computer. My domains are hosted with GoDaddy.

I have always had one computer with my localhost on it working perfectly fine on port 80. Now I'd like to add in this second computer and be able to access it from outside my local network. I've set the port forwarding to 8079 and the listening port to 8079 on apache on the second computer. But from this point, I have no idea how to differentiate between the two. Or even if I can?

I want WebsiteOne to point to ComputerOne on port 80 and WebsiteTwo to point to ComputerTwo on port 8079. If this is possible, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, by using port forwarding you can do that my friend.

1. Point your domains as your desire. WebOne -> routerip:80 and webTwo -> routerip:8079
2. Configure the port forwarding in your router so any request to the port 80 will be routed to the WebOne destined server and any request to the port 8079 will be routed to the WebTwo destined server

Configuration on the router may vary for each router but the bottom line is the same.

Hope it can help you mate.